# Accessing angular2 directive from component

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive

I have created a directive for a textarea (TextAreaExt) and i want to call a method of that directive from a component it is used in. The selector of the directive is "textarea" (no attribute, affects all textarea elements). In my component if i do the following:

```
@ViewChild('TextAreaExt') txt: TextAreaExt;
```

I can call methods on txt successfully. But what if i had multiple textareas? I would like to do it like this instead:

```
@ViewChild('txt') txt: TextAreaExt;
```

Unfortunately, the above line does not return a TextAreaExt class, but instead returns an ElementRef.

How could i solve this problem so that i could have multiple text areas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
@ViewChild('txt', {read: TextAreaExt}) txt: TextAreaExt;
```

If there are more directives, components or other DI tokens registered for an element, `read` allows you to specify, which one you want to get returned.

Comment: Thank you! Worked like a charm